# typescript how to enforce type for specific key in interface?

Tags: typescript

I want this interface to know that if the key is `'num'` then it can only be number type or undefined but it currently is under the coverage of `string | number | undefined`;

```
export interface StringNumber {
  [k: string]: string | number | undefined;
  num: number | undefined;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgZRimQHMA5AVwFsAjNOAbwCg44BtAawC44BnI0gF0e-YkhJwAPnCTU6UKXApIAJsHTJgKgNwsZ1HrNr1pytRqRbdAXyZNsEJPziYehMeTn0AvIz1GeAHJ0CAhAgBoma10gA

Comment: @zerkms yes in your example it errors. I want this interface to accept something like { a: 'a', 1: 1}

Comment: I don't think you can have number as key in javascript / typescript

Comment: @zerkms sorry I meant to do this { a: 'a', num: 1}

Comment: It errors correctly, showing that the type `number | undefined` is enforced for the key `num`. The interface in your question does accept `{a: 'a', num: 1}`.

Comment: @Psidom You sort-of can. The object literal `{ 1: 2 }` is valid JavaScript, but it's really just shorthand for `{ '1': 2 }` (`Object.keys` gives `['1']`).

Comment: Your example, as posted, seems to work just fine: https://tsplay.dev/m3z5AN In what situations does it not work?